# Windowsによるgvimでのneosnippetの利用

Tags: vim

Windows10のgvimでneosnippetの利用を考えています。
Luaを入れていないためneocomplcache, neosnippet, neosnippet-snippetsの3つのプラグインを導入して利用しようと考えていますが、neocomplcacheのみを入れた時点で
`vimproc's DLL: c:/Users/hoge/.cache/dein/repos/........./lib/vimproc_wind64.dll" is not found. Please read :help vimproc and make it.`
のエラー？が出て来るわ補完候補は表示されないわでダメダメな状況です。
一応
`let g:neocomplcache_enable_at_startup = 1`
は.vimrcに書いてあるのですがそれ以外にも記述する必要があるでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

メッセージのとおりだと思います
vimprocも入れてやってmakeして、OSの環境ごとに異なる、今回の場合はvimproc_wind64.dllを作ってやらないと駄目みたいですが、makeしました?
Windowsだと、makeの環境を作るのが面倒ですね
おんなじように考える人はやはりいるようで、[vimproc に Windows の DLL ダウンロード機能を入れた](http://thinca.hatenablog.com/entry/20160302/1456892154) という記事が有りました
kaoriya版のvimなら楽ができそうです

Comment: kaoriya版使用でvimproc に Windows の DLL ダウンロード機能を入れた の記事に書いて有ることをそのままやったら無事できました。
ありがとうございました。